# Python: How to append to a (sparse) 2-d array on both axes?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to read some 2d matrices from csv flatfiles sitting somewhere on my filesystem and then collate them as I go across and then down. The csv files contain sparse data and lets say that I have only the following 4 files

```
file_001.csv            file_002.csv
-----------             ----------
11,0,0,0,0,11           22,0,0,0,0,22
0,0,0,0,0,0             0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0             0,0,0,0,0,0
11,0,0,0,0,11           22,0,0,0,0,22

file_003.csv            file_004.csv
-----------             ----------
33,0,0,0,0,33           44,0,0,0,0,44
0,0,0,0,0,0             0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0             0,0,0,0,0,0
33,0,0,0,0,33           44,0,0,0,0,44
```

What I would like to end up with is the following:

```
11,0,0,0,0,11,22,0,0,0,0,22
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
11,0,0,0,0,11,22,0,0,0,0,22
33,0,0,0,0,33,44,0,0,0,0,44
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
33,0,0,0,0,33,44,0,0,0,0,44
```

The csv files shown above contain values at the 4 corners only but in real life that doesnt have to be the case. I have done this way here for our convenience only, to keep track of the individual files within the final result.

However in real life the data will be sparse. Also the array in each csv will be 2000-by-2000 in size and I will be stitching together 20 array going across and 23 going down. Hence the final (big sparse) array will be 46000-by-40000

What I have come up with is the following. Is there a better (more efficient and/or faster) way please? Any comments to improve that are highly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix, hstack

def mosaic(csv_root):
    out = None
    tiles_across = 2
    tiles_down = 2
    tiles = []
    step = 0
    for j in range(tiles_down):
        # loop over the rows and for each row stitch all csvs. The keep them in a list
        csvs = [f"file_{int(i+j*tiles_across):03d}.csv" for i in range(tiles_across)]
        filenames = [os.path.join(csv_root, csv) for csv in csvs]
        df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, index_col=False, header=None) for f in filenames], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
        coo = coo_matrix(df.values)
        coo.row += step
        tiles.append(coo)
        step = coo.shape[0] + step

    # concatenate now the elements of the list
    [M, N] = tiles[0].shape
    M = M * len(tiles)  # adjust the coordinates
    _row = np.concatenate([x.row for x in tiles]).ravel().tolist()
    _col = np.concatenate([x.col for x in tiles]).ravel().tolist()
    _data = np.concatenate([x.data for x in tiles]).ravel().tolist()
    out = coo_matrix((_data, (_row, _col)), shape=(M, N))
    print(out)
    return out


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_dir = os.path.join('my', 'path', 'to', 'csv', 'root')

    mosaic(my_dir)
```

Comment: A quick suggestion - collect all the individual `coo` matrices in a list of lists.  Then use `sparse.bmat` to join them into one sparse matrix.  Look at its code.  `sparse.hstack` (and `vstack`) also make use of `bmat`.

Comment: Ah yes, that sounds like a good idea. Hadnt heard of `sparse.bmat` before